# BASH: Run two commands in parallel and wait for the second one to finish

Tags: multithreading, bash, asynchronous, parallel-processing, wait

I have two commands, one is logging things in the background and won't stop until I kill it and the second one will eventually stop.

Let's mark them A and B respectively.

I want to execute:

- A and B in parallel
- Wait for B to finish
- Kill A
- [do some more stuff]

and repeat that in a loop.

I'm running on MacOS and can't update to Bash 4.x because of GPLv3.

Preferably A (the logger) would start first but I wouldn't mind if it's undefined or B would start first since the difference in time is negligible.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `A & pid=$!; B; kill $pid`?

Comment: @Cyrus, wouldn't this execute A and only when A is done execute B?

I'll try it out but the logs I'm generating are enormous, altogether almost a TB in size so I don't want to run it for nothing.

Comment: @Ron, to help you understand Cyrus' answer, read in `man bash` about _control operator &_.

Comment: No. Replace `A` by `sleep 20` and `B` by `sleep 5` and watch what happens.

Comment: You certainly can install `bash v4` on a Mac, by the way. If you use **homebrew** it is just `brew install bash` - of course, you or your employer may have additional constraints but in general you are free to use `bash v4`.

Comment: @Mark I know, and the reason you stated is exactly why I can't :)

Oh and thanks everyone.